# How to select a certain element with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to write some code that grabs a solution from slader (just screwing around with the library). Trying to use the `.find()` method to a select a certain div with a certain class, but I end up just getting None as a result. This is my first asked question on stack overflow, please comment if you need more clarification. Thanks to anyone who solves this in advance!

```
slader = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781305266643-stewart-multivariable-calculus-8th/879/exercises/9c')
soup = BeautifulSoup(slader,'html.parser')

solution = soup.find("div", class_ = "solution-content")
print(solution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this `solution = soup.find("div", {'class': 'solution-content'})`.
However incase of the url that you wanted to fetch data from, the div is loaded lazily. Meaning it is loaded after some time via ajax. So when you fetch the resp the content is not available. It is better if you could do some analysis on using chrome dev tools to identify these things.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will definitely look into that.